# Why does querying a report from google play console by the google cloud BigQuery API give incomplete results

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-play-console, google-cloud-data-transfer

I'm trying to get data from one of the reports available in the google play console. Specifically the user_acquisition report. I set up the data transfer service within the google cloud platform in order to use the BigQuery API.

When querying that specific report the results are partial. Some columns match the results I get when downloading the report manually but other columns just have the value `null` although the downloaded report shows that there should be numerical values there.

Another peculiar thing is that when specifying a date range for the query (month of may for example) the result will show about 1/3 of the dates in that month but there should be a row for each day of the month.

When looking at the transfer runs history, some of the runs have completed successfully, and some have failed giving the error message: `Error code 5 : No files found for any reports. Please make sure you selected the correct Google Cloud Storage bucket and Google Play reports exist.` But if no files are found, then how am i getting any results at all?

The users of both the GCP and Google Play Console are the owners of the project, so there shouldn't be any issue with the permissions to access the bucket where the reports are stored.

I tried creating another data transfer service to see if it can even find the reports. It did find some of the files but not the one I'm interested in. The transfer run history shows the same error as mentioned above.

Has anyone had some similar problem before and perhaps can offer some sort of solution? Or maybe just has some insights into why this problem is occurring?

Comment: How are you querying your reports? I think the null values might be related if those are placed at the reports names.

Comment: @sergiofranco I'm just choosing the needed report from the dataset in the BigQuery platform and just selecting all, just to see what results I get from that table/report.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue could be related with the availability of the desired report, since I've found that only some reports are [supported by this service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/play-transfer#supported_reports):

- Detailed reports (Reviews, Financial reports)
- Aggregated reports (Statistics, User acquisition)

Could it happen that the specific report your want to export is not supported?

If that's not the case I think you should file a support case sharing the "Resource name" into the Transfer details of the failed exports (and correct ones for reference). Alternatively of the support ticket you can also report a defect on the transfer service on a [Public Issue tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=815827&template=1395449). The support team can help you to review further the error message.